# Ember Data: Saving a model with an association in one request

Tags: javascript, rest, ember.js, ember-data

I have two ember models with a relationship like this

```
App.Foo = DS.Model.extend
   bar: DS.belongsTo("App.Bar", embedded: true)

App.Bar = DS.Model.extend
   primaryKey: "blah"
   blah: DS.attr "string
```

If I create and save a new record like this:

```
foo = App.store.createRecord App.Foo
foo.set "bar", App.Bar.createRecord(blah: "blahblah")
App.store.commit()
```

I see 2 post requests to the server:

```
URL: /foos
Payload: {"foo":{"bar":null}}
```

and

```
URL: /bars
Payload: {"bar":{"blah":"blahblah"}}
```

The association is embedded so I would like to see:

```
URL: /foos
Payload: {"foo":{"bar":{"blah":"blahblah"}}}
```

Can I achieve this with the ember-data REST adapter or do I need to write my own code to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I am observing the same behavior in my application. 
Setting 'embedded' to true only helps you get data as embedded, but while you post it separate requests will be generated. 
You have write your in code if you want to achieve it in one request.

Comment: Ember-data does not currently support committing changes via embedded associations. The `DS.Store.commit()` logic could be revised to introspect associations and use embedded data, but `createRecord`, `updateRecord`, & `deleteRecord`, (& their plurals for bulk commits) would also need to be adapted to correctly update the state of the associated objects.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but for what it's worth I've found that "fighting" Ember's design by trying to save multiple models at once led me down a terrible path.

It is much easier and more reliable to add the required attributes for a new `Bar` to `Foo` and then create and return the new objects on the server, like so:

```
App.Foo = DS.Model.extend({
  blah: DS.attr('string'),
  barName: DS.attr('string'),
  bar: DS.belongsTo('bar')
})

this.store.createRecord('foo', { blah: "stuff", barName: "foo" }).save()

# => POST /foos

Request:
{ foo: { blah: "stuff", bar_name: "boo" } }

Response:
{ foo: { id: 1, blah: "stuff", bar: { id: 1, name: "boo" } } }
```

Yes, you end up with an unused attribute on `Foo`, but you save yourself a lot of code.